# Decrypting passwords that are stored on server with mcrypt

Tags: php, encryption, passwords, mcrypt

So I have a table that has encrypted usernames and passwords under varbinary using MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 encryption. I can store encrypted details fine, but I have problems decrypting them. I'm storing the username, password and the IV when the user registers.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users ( username, password ) VALUES ( :user, :pass) ";

$encrypt_user = $_POST['username'];
$encrypt_pass = $_POST['password'];

$encrypted_user = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $secret_key, $encrypt_user, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
$encrypted_pass = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $secret_key, $encrypt_pass, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
$encrypted_cardnumber = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $secret_key, 

$query_params = array(
    ':user' => $encrypted_user,
    ':pass' => $encrypted_pass,
);

try {
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
}
```

This stores all fine, the question is when I want to decrypt. How can I fetch the IV for the user that logged in? I have tried setting the iv to a session variable when the user registers but I know that only works when a user first registers and then logs in.

```
$query = "SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE username = :username";

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
//encrypting the username and password to compare to the ones stored in the databaase
$encrypted_username = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $secret_key, $username, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
$encrypted_password = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $secret_key, $password, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just don't encrypt the username, as this is no sensitive information. But you should change the method from encrypting to hashing. Because with the IV and the secret_key it's possible to decrypt the password.

Comment: but even if I don't encrypt the username, how can i decrypt the password that somebody enters, there could be many IVs in the table.

Comment: You already have a stub for querying by username. When you stored the IV also in the DB you first grab the database entry by username, then hash the given password with the IV and check if the hashed password matches the one from the database

Comment: Let me give this a try.

Comment: And when using php5.5 take a look [here](http://php.net/manual/de/function.password-hash.php)

Comment: Hey thanks for the pointer I got it! I didn't change to hashing but didn't encrypt the username like you said.